# Can a Userevent script be called from another Suitescript ie Suitelet or Scheduled Script?

Tags: netsuite

I am running in a strange scenario.
I need to call a UE from another Suitescript .
Is it programatically possible ?

Comment: Read about [JSONP[(http://json-p.org/), seems your best bet to do something like this. You could just pull a certain function with a nlapiRequestURL and run it in the current UE.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can trigger user event scripts from Scheduled scripts and Suitelets.  The only type of script that won't trigger a user event script is another user event script

Comment: This scenario explains why I could not trigger a UE from another UE.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on what you mean by "call a UE". Do you just need to call function(s) that are currently in a UE script? Or do you want the actual record-level events to fire in order to trigger the UE?

If you just need to share functions between different scripts, then I recommend moving the common functions to their own .js file and including that new file as a Library on the scripts that need those functions.

If you need the record-level events to fire, then Rusty is correct. If you perform an `nlapiLoadRecord`, `nlapiSubmitRecord`, or `nlapiSubmitField` from any script except another UE script, NetSuite will fire the appropriate events, and your UE code will execute.

Comment: will this solution work for Suitescript 2? A simple load and save of a record would work?

Comment: Yes, the event chaining works the same in 1.0 and 2.x. `N/record.load()` invoked from any script module *except* for a User Event will fire that record type's `beforeLoad` events; similarly `N/record.save()` will trigger that record type's `beforeSubmit` and `afterSubmit` events.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct - the whole idea of a UE script is that it is a server-side, record-level script. Whenever the record with the UE script attached is created, loaded, modified, the record level events are fired and scripts are executed.

With more specific business requirements and explanation of what you're trying to do, maybe we can get you a definitive "yes/no and how to" to address your need.